# How to convert an input from L to [H|T] in prolog?

Tags: prolog

say if I have to create a function in prolog:
dosomething(L).
how can I make it into something that does the same thing as:
dosomething([H|T]) where L = [H|T] so I can split the list?

Comment: Not clear what you are up to. Can you make an example?

Comment: Just write it as `dosomething([H|T])`. Prolog will unify the list argument with `[H|T]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can [*unify*](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse5) `L` with `[H|T]`:

```
dosomething(L) :- L = [H|T], ...
```

which is the same as:

```
dosomething([H|T]) :- ...
```

Only if `L` is `[]` (or is not a list) then it cannot unify with `[H|T]`:

```
?- [H|T] = [].
false.
```